# How to format number to represent time?

Tags: python, formatting

I'm looking to format a simple integer i.e. `1` to print out `01:00 am`. Reading the python string formatting made it even more confusing, right now what I have is `"02"` which will give me `01` but that's about it :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use string formatting to do this. You should use the [`str.format()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#format) method, which is the preferred method - the old method (using the modulo (`%`) operator) is outdated and recommended against for new code:

```
>>> hour = 1
>>> am_pm = "am"
>>> print('{:02d}:00 {}'.format(hour, am_pm))
01:00 am
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always use this format

```
print '%02d:00 %s' % (hour, am_pm)
```

where `hour` contains your integer value, and `am_pm` the appropriate string for `am` or `pm`.

There are other ways to format strings, e.g., using the `str.format` method, but this is simple and works:

```
>>> am_pm = 'am'
>>> hour = 10
>>> print '%02d:00 %s' % (hour, am_pm)
10:00 am

>>> hour = 3
>>> am_pm = 'pm'
>>> print '%02d:00 %s' % (hour, am_pm)
03:00 pm
```